# How do I make a duplicate of a directory tree with symlinks duplicated relatively?

Tags: rsync, cp

I want to duplicate directory 'foo' and all its subdirectories to 'foo_copy'.

1) I don't want 'foo_copy' to have several copies of some files or directories with one copy for each symlink to the file or directories.

2) I don't want 'foo_copy's symlinks to point back to the 'foo' directory.

I want an exact duplicate with:

1) 'foo_copy's files and directories residing in the same place as they did in 'foo' except now in 'foo_copy'.

2) 'foo_copy's symlinks pointing to the same files or directories they had pointed to in 'foo' except now in 'foo_copy'.

I don't know if my links are absolute or relative. I'm hoping for a solution that would work either way.

Bonus points, this is for Mac (FreeBSD) with `rsync` version 2.6.9 protocol version 29.

Comment: Are your existing symlinks absolute or relative?

Comment: What version of `rsync` do you have?

Comment: I have rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29.
I don't know if my links are absolute or relative.  I'm hoping for a solution that would work either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some alternatives to `cp` (which I am going to assume someone will answer with the BSD version of) are the standard POSIX utility `pax`:

```
$ cd foo
$ install -d ../foo_copy
$ pax -r -w -p p * ../foo_copy/
```

Apple's [ditto](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ditto.1.html):

```
$ ditto foo foo_copy
```

the tool that you asked about, which has some subtle gotchas, but fortunately the only one that you will hit here is the necessity to use trailing slashes:

```
$ rsync --archive --hard-links --extended-attributes foo/ foo_copy/
```

and of course the *duplicate* function (<kbd>⌘ Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>) in the Finder.

## Further reading

- [Using rsync to backup | Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224747/)